# Any way to make an Iterator<E> emitted from ArrayList have remove() blocked WITHOUT creating two Iterators?

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

ArrayList's Iterator class ArrayList.Itr is private, so I can't subclass that guy.

The things ArrayList.Itr access in ArrayList are private, so I cannot provide my own implementation.

The only way I can see how to do this is to subclass ArrayList, override iterator(), take that iterator and **wrap & delegate** it to my own Iterator object that denies access to remove.  (Or wrap and delegate ArrayList itself and do the same thing)

**Collections.unmodifiableList** does the same thing, basically.

But this would cause two objects to be created each and every time MyArrayList.iterator() is called, which in my environment is suboptimal.

Ideas?

edit:

In this environment, GCing small objects is a **major major problem**. This environment calls list iterators **hundreds of millions** of times in very short periods. We need as little GC thrashing as possible.  This is not premature optimization.  This is very late optimization.  This is not some toy app.  This is a clustered web-scale system that is running at the absolute limit of the hardware.

Comment: Why do you need to stop remove() calls? Are you writing an API?

Comment: I want the list to be immutable.  Collections.unmodifiableList creates two objects when Iterator is called.

Comment: Are you prematurely optimizing by insisting that 2 objects is unacceptable?  It wouldn't have to duplicate the whole list, just wrap and delegate to it (except for remove()), so memory shouldn't be an issue, and constructing a wrapper should be fast -- practically free.

Comment: Why are you concerned about the two additional objects? These are just wrappers, and are very cheap to create and garbage collect. Have you measured that it caused a problem? Or are you prematurely omptimizing, which is the root of all evil?

Comment: They built and already optimized `Collections.unmodifiable()` many years ago. Do you seriously think you can do better than the creators and maintainers of platform? I got a secret for you it creates more objects than you think it does, you aren't going to do any better.

Comment: In this environment, GCing small objects is a MAJOR MAJOR problem.  This environment calls list iterators HUNDREDS OF MILLIONS of times in very short periods.  We need as little GC thrashing as possible.

Comment: Have you measured or at least observed it? Or are you thinking it's a major problem?

Comment: Yes, of course we have measured this.

Comment: +1 balanced unnecessary downvote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Collections.unmodifiable` list, as you mention, is probably the best way to go. I doubt that you have indeed profiled your program as a whole and found out that the creation of iterators is indeed a bottle neck in the execution.

Actually, Java creates tons and tons of temporary objects. This is not good per see, but due to this it is very optimized to do it efficiently.

Btw, the fact that you're trying to access private members of the ArrayList actually smells a little. Why not create an iterator based on `size()` and `get(int index)` if you really don't want to create two objects when iterating over the list?

Comment: I like this idea of creating an iterator based off get and size.  This is perfect.  Thanks.

Comment: This is not perfect. What happens if you (or another programmer) later decide to replace ArrayList with LinkedList? This Iterator implementation is not generic, it is bound to a specific collection, in a subtle way. I wish I could really see how this application works, and compare the performance of this, let's say, 'optimized' solution against the most obvious, neat and correct one (wrapping the iterator).

Comment: If your application bottleneck is really tons of garbage iterators, I think you should avoid using iterators and Java Collections and go for a really micro-optimized solution (custom data structures tailored to your needs) which doesn't create tons of objects. If the bottleneck is really this one, then that get(int index) thingie won't last ...

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own subclass of `AbstractList`, based on the `ArrayList` code. I initially thought this was a horrible idea, but if this is a critical issue for you, it's not a large class.

Answer (score 1):

Don't micro-optimize Java. The bottleneck of your application won't be the "doubling" of this Iterator, **take it for granted**.

Your solution is smart and just fine, concentrate on other (more relevant) issues, instead.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but in this particular environment GCing small objects is a major issue.  100,000,000 iterator objects is bad enough.  200M makes us thrash more.

Comment: If you have 100M iterators living in your application, your application design is probably flawed.

Comment: No joke the design is flawed.  That is not something I can change.  I'm just trying to squeeze a little more performance out of this pig.